# Async and await Methods

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a clarification regarding async and await methods in C# in a practical application. Consider the following flow which is a simple version of the working code:

**Helper.cs**

```
public class Helper
{
   public CustomDTP _customDTO = null;
   public async Task<Analysis> GetAnalysis(string name, int id,string option)
        {

          if(option == "a")
           {
             //Call ThirdParty service and get Data
             _CustomDTO.Data1 = await GetData1(name,id);
           }
          else if(option == "b")
           {
             //Call ThirdParty service and get Data
             _CustomDTO.Data2 = await GetData2(name,id);
           }
          return _customDTO;
        }
}
```

**FunctionController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("ProcessData")]
    public async Task<string> ProcessData(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {

            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var Result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            info = js.Deserialize<CustomDTO>(Result);

            Helper Servc = new Helper();

            var DetailData = await Servc.GetAnalysis(info);

            Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DetailData);
        return Data;
       }
```

**processing.js**

```
//Knockout js application

self.compositionComplete = function()
{
  self.Data1();
  self.Data2();
}
 self.Data1 = function () {
            var getURL = Url + "/ProcessData";
            var initData = {
                "name": self.name,
                "id": self.id,
                "option": "a"
            }
        $.ajax({
                url: getURL,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",                
                data: JSON.stringify(initData),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    //Rendering Data Logic for Option a
        });
}

self.Data2 = function () {
            var getURL = Url + "/ProcessData";
            var initData = {
                "name": self.name,
                "id": self.id,
                "option": "b"
            }
        $.ajax({
                url: getURL,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",                
                data: JSON.stringify(initData),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    //Rendering Data Logic for Option b
        });
}
```

Now , the issue is `GetData1()` of Third party service takes less time (eg :  2 seconds) and `GetData2()` takes more time(eg: 100 seconds) . The idea of making two ajax calls and using **async** and **await** was to render the **self.Data1** on the screen and do  not wait until **self.Data2** has been retrieved .
Unfortunately in this it is not happening , I will have to wait for 100 seconds for both **Data 1** and **Data 2** to be shown on the screen . What is that I need to change to ensure separate threads are used for **GetData1** and *GetData2* .

One more observation is that , if I call **self.Data2** on success on **self.Data1()** like below, I am able to see **Data1** on the screen instantly but that is not what I am looking for . I need both Data1 and Data2 to be rendered parallely and aschrynously .

```
self.Data1 = function () {
            var getURL = Url + "/ProcessData";
            var initData = {
                "name": self.name,
                "id": self.id,
                "option": "a"
            }
        $.ajax({
                url: getURL,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",                
                data: JSON.stringify(initData),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    self.Data2();
        });
}
```

I am sure that the thread is getting blocked after using await but I am not able to get the resolution for making separate calls and render **Data1** and **Data2** parallely. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Hi, have you try to async the ajax, may help as the Data2 will not wait for Data1 to finish like so   ---   async : true --- after POST

Comment: @WindyHen By default $.ajax calls are async in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but everything seems to be okay. I didn't work with `knockout` how ever this part seems to me "wait until all task complete" or something like that

```
self.compositionComplete = function()
{
  self.Data1();
  self.Data2();
}
```

something like fired when both of them is finished. Maybe you can use different `self`.